# It's possible to trigger an action in my Air app, from a link in a webview?

Tags: windows, webview, air, adobe, desktop-application

I'm planning on create a desktop app for a customer, which will be basically a webview (displaying some page only accessible in this app), and two widgets.

But this page needs to have a couple of links/buttons that will trigger some events (outside the webview, obviously) in the app, calling the widgets.
It is possible? How?

I've made a little research and didn't found any resource on that. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to call Action Script 3 (and also you can call JS methods from AS3) methods using ExternalInterface (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cb2.html).